# Bazel: FlywayDB java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, java-8, classloader, flyway, bazel

I am using bazel to run a java8 project. 
I get the following with exception with flywaydb version 5.1.4.
I understand what the error says but I do not want to use java 9. I want to stick to java8. Does that mean i need to downgrade flywaydb or what? Also why is the class loader loading java9 files in the first place anyway.

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:` module-info has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

How do i get around this without using java9. Perhaps this had to do with bazel...I did not have this problem when i used maven with flywaydb version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little to do with libraries that you use; to put it simple: you have a class that has been compiled with `java -9` (thus `53`) and you try to run it on an environment that can only handle up to `52` versions.

You also have `module-info` in there, which implies modularization, thus higher than java-8. If the error comes from a class from a library, like `flywaydb` - simply downgrade to the latest java-8 supported artifact.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to downgrade flyway but that solved the problem indeed. flywaydb 5.0.3

Comment: generally if that project moved to java-9, it might not support java-8 artifacts for long, so you might be planning for an upgrade... and you could accept the answer if it helped...